# Is there a way to write single prepare function for all the KPIs in Gramex

Tags: gramex

I have a common function which needs to be evaluated before executing all the KPIs. So I wrote a prepare function but prepare function is calling for all the KPIs separately. Instead I want a prepare function to be executed once for the each endpoint. My endpoint is like this

```
project-test:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/test
    handler: FormHandler
    kwargs:
      auth: &AUTH
        login_url: /$YAMLURL/login
      kpi1:
        prepare: validations.validate_request(args, handler)
        url: $CONNECTION_STRING
        queryfunction: queries.query1(args) 
      kpi2:
        prepare: validations.validate_request(args, handler)
        url: $CONNECTION_STRING
        queryfunction: queries.query2(args)
      modify: project.refactor(data, handler)
```

I tried to giving prepare function in the kwargs but getting

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you shared is correct. The error may be in one of the custom functions, e.g. `validations.validate_request`, `queries.query*` or `project.refactor`

To test this, I created the following `data1.csv`

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

... and `data2.csv`

```
a,b
4,5
6,7
```

This is my `gramex.yaml`

```yaml
url:
  project-test:
      pattern: /$YAMLURL/test
      handler: FormHandler
      kwargs:
        kpi1:
          prepare: validations.validate_request(args, handler)
          url: data1.csv
        kpi2:
          prepare: validations.validate_request(args, handler)
          url: data2.csv
```

... and this is my `validations.py`:

```py
def validate_request(args, handler):
    print(args, handler)
    args['_c'] = ['a']    # Filter column 'a' alone
```

When I visit `/test`, the output only shows column 'a':

```json
{"kpi1":[{"a":1},{"a":3}],"kpi2":[{"a":4},{"a":6}]}
```

... and the command prompt shows that the prepare function is called once for each dataset:

```
{'_limit': [10000]} <gramex.services.FormHandler object at 0x000001B1C14A43C8>
{'_limit': [10000]} <gramex.services.FormHandler object at 0x000001B1C14A43C8>
```

Perhaps you could share the full error message about where the AttributeError appeared? That might help.

Comment: The endpoint which I wrote is working fine @S Anand, but I want to modify it something like below
`url:
  project-test:
      pattern: /$YAMLURL/test
      handler: FormHandler
      kwargs:
        prepare: validations.validate_request(args, handler)
        kpi1:
          url: data1.csv
        kpi2:
          url: data2.csv`
one prepare function that should apply for all the KPI's inside the endpoint which is causing the above error

Comment: Ah, I understand. No, we can't do that. You can re-use the same function but have to specify it independently for each dataset. That's because when there are multiple datasets, Gramex doesn't know whether `prepare:` is the name of a dataset/KPI, or a function to call.

Comment: Thanks, Manoj. Could you please mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is more of a prepare function issue. Could you please check if you are trying to access a string using its key. Just a quick hypothesis - check if any of your dict is in json/ string format.